# Conversão de object para float

Tags: pandas

Tenho um dataframe com uma coluna com valores:

```
0         411,90
1         394,88
2           0,01
3           0,01
```

Em um arquivo csv, todas as colunas do meu df tem tipagem de 'object', quando tento converter as colunas que possuem valores como a do exemplo acima o python me responde com o erro:

`df[coluna] = df[coluna].astype(float)`

`ValueError: could not convert string to float: '411,90'`

Tentei importar o arquivo da seguinte forma:

`df = pd.read_csv('base.csv', sep=';', encoding='UTF-8')`

Mas também não consigo converter as colunas para float, alguém tem alguma sugestão?

Answer (score 2):

Olá!

Então, isso acontece porque o número está sendo lido como string.

Sugiro que você altere essa vírgula nos números por um ponto, dessa forma:

```
df['coluna'] = df['coluna'].str.replace(',','.')
```

Em seguida, tente realizar a conversão novamente..

```
df[coluna] = df[coluna].astype(float)
```

ou faça tudo em uma linha:

```
df['coluna'] = df['coluna'].str.replace(',','.').astype(float)
```

Espero ter ajudado! =]